# Linux daemon: how to store the data that is often updated

Tags: linux, daemon, datastore

I work mostly with embedded systems (PIC microcontrollers), but I have no experience in Linux system programming.

I'm already reading the book "Linux System Programming" by Robert Love, which gives me basic understanding how should my program talk to the kernel, how do things work, etc.

Now, I need to write a daemon that should monitor per-application internet activity, and store bandwidth of each application. (it's like "nethogs" utility, but my daemon should run all the time and store statistics, unlike nethogs) Although I really need for such a statistics (bandwidth per application), I would write that daemon mostly in educational purposes, so I don't care if this is a kind of reinventing the wheel.

The question is short: what is preferred method to store the data?

Say, my daemon will wake up every second, grab current upload/download speed and applications that caused that network activity, store it somewhere, and sleep again.

I see two ways to store the data:

- Implement my own data format, some kind of text file. I don't like this, because it's hard to make it extensible and so on; I would rely on some existing solution that fits to my needs well;
- Use database: say, sqlite. I'm not sure if this is good idea to write to the database each second, since this is probably expensive. Probably I should store data in the RAM for a minute, and flush it to the database only after that, but if some client is connected that displays real-time stats, then flush data each second anyway?

Not sure about all of this. Probably there are some different, better approaches? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You should check out [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool). You can probably use some interface to it or at least the same concepts for your needs here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but actually I don't want round-robin database, I want statistics to be kept, so that I can later examine hourly/daily/monthly/etc bandwidth per application.

Comment: will the client be running on the same machine?

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7, yes, right now I don't care about any remote access (if I want it, I can just connect via ssh and then run the client)

Comment: for storage, you are correct, you have 2 options, either invent a new super-efficient storage layout, or (2) use a database to handle your needs. If you are going to be storing data perpetually, and in the large quantities it will ultimately generate, you are probably better off with a database. (mariadb, postgressql, or sqlite) are a few, but depending on your access needs, dbm, ndbm, etc may be better suited. The database benefit is that storage and retrieval code is thoroughly tested. With the next gee-whiz storage system, your mileage may vary...

Comment: Then you can do one thing, have the server send the data to be stored through messages to both a database daemon and the client if it is running at the same time. You can use any messaging library for this purpose. The database daemon can cache these messages and store them say after every min. And in the mean while the client will also have the latest updated data per second and it wont need to query the database again and again for live data. But it can accesss the database for old data. How about that?

Comment: I would say, send you data to graphite server (or statsd). Another nice things would be to write this as a collectd plugin (which gives you a framework to collect and store metrics) – but if you want to write a daemon by yourself, graphite would be the simplest option probably.

Comment: While in general I don't recommend RRDtool, you should not reject it if your only reason is the one you mentioned above.  RRDtool can, in fact, keep your data for as long as you like; you just have to specify the retention period you want.

Comment: Why do you guys all write your suggestions as comments, not answers? =) It's not so convenient to communicate with each of you this way. Thank you very much for suggestions; @spinus, graphite / collectd way looks very interesting, thanks for that, I'll probably try it. (4aRkKn1gh7, collectd is probably a particular solution of what you suggested, too; right?) dg99, could you please elaborate why you don't recommend RRDtool in general?